# Recommended way to query & evaluate xpath (c#)

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, xpath

Writing in c# - I want to query an XML.
Before doing that I decided to check the well formness of it using xsd validation.

back in my java days I use to build and evaluate xpath queries using (pricey) xmlspy.
Is there a free tool that can help me build queries?
Is there a more recommended way doing those queries?
Now that I am on VS2010 is there maybe a way to do it in the studio?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Xpath Visualizer (Disclaimer: completely Open Source and non-commercial) has been around for more than 10 years and many thousands of people have learnt with it XPath -- the fun way.

Can be downloaded from Lars Huttar's site:

**http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html**

Answer (score 1):

This one is quite old, but it may be what you want:  the XPath Expression Test Application  at http://www.keylimetie.com/blog/2006/5/4/xpathexpressions.

Liquid also sells an XML tool that can do this (Liquid XML Studio), and there is a Starter Edition at about $100. More at http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xpath-viewer.aspx.